# Lightning web component not displaying the data

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, trailhead

I am doing a trailhead challenge  https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-web-components-basics.
I created a lightning web component and added it to a app page  but i am unable to see the UI page in my org and any data of the default page .
Please find the screenshot attached

JS file :

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class BikeCard extends LightningElement {
    name = 'Electra X4';
    description = 'A sweet bike built for comfort.';
    category = 'Mountain';
    material = 'Steel';
    price = '$2,700';
    pictureUrl = 'https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sfdc-demo/ebikes/electrax4.jpg';
}
```

Meta.Xml file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>51.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
       <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Html file :

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <div>Name: {name}</div>
        <div>Description: {description}</div>
        <lightning-badge label={material}></lightning-badge>
        <lightning-badge label={category}></lightning-badge>
        <div>Price: {price}</div>
        <div><img src={pictureUrl}/></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image]

Comment: did you add this component on lightning page ??

Comment: Did you try to clean a cache?

Comment: Hi , Yes i added the component to lightning  page

Comment: i tried to clear the cache and refreshed the page still seeing the same issues1) Setup > Security > Session Settings > Caching.

2) Uncheck Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance

Comment: I created another scratch org and i was able to see the output  not sure why in case of another org

Answer (score 0):

I tried clearing cache now and pushed the changes to the org it worked now and i can see the ouptput